# Android ProgressDialog colours inverting randomly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, progressdialog

I have several ProgressDialogs through the android application I am working on. They are all used in exactly the same manner, and appear the same throughout the entire app except for the login screen where the entire ProgressDialog inverts colors - White background with black text changes to a darkblack background with white text. This happens on the Galaxy S3 but not on an older samsung which runs 2.3. Below shows the 2 examples (declaration moved to above instantiation for SO purposes)

```
public static ProgressDialog loginProgressDialog = null;

/* show progress */
loginProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

loginProgressDialog.setTitle("Title - Removed for SO");
loginProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while signing in...");
loginProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
loginProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);               

loginProgressDialog.show();
```

Above is the code for the login dialogue with the randomly inverted colours on the S3

Below is the code which displays the ProgressDialog normally in 4-5 places of the app they all follow the same style as below:

```
/* show progress */
public static ProgressDialog timedstartProgressDialog = null;

timedstartProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

timedstartProgressDialog.setTitle("Title - Removed for SO");
timedstartProgressDialog.setMessage("Get Ready!");
timedstartProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
timedstartProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

timedstartProgressDialog.show();
```

I am struggling to understand why A) It happens on the S3 but not on the older samsung phone, and B) what is causing this to only invert on the login screen and not on the other 4-5 activities throughout the app.

It is probably something very simple, or maybe phone dependent, but I can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.graphics.drawable.*;


ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);
final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null,null));
String MyColor = "#FF00FF";
pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(MyColor));
ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable,Gravity.LEFT,ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
pg.setProgressDrawable(progress);   
pg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
pg.setProgress(45);
```

Comment: Thanks - while this will help, it doesn't explain the underlying issue.

Comment: This looks more like a hack than a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755731/showing-two-progressdialog-instead-one -- somewhat similar issue I'm facing