# Showing two ProgressDialog instead one

Tags: android, view, styles, double, progressdialog

When I use samsung galaxy mini 4.4 I see two progressDialog(picture below). When I use another device - everething is okay

[image]

```
if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogThemeBlackColor);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_your_data));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and strange this is, its happening on only some Samsung devices and too for only some apps, other mine apps with almost same code don't have this issue... its really really strange thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found reason, but I found a way to avoid this. Need to create a dialog in the following manner:

```
new ProgressDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.ProgressDialog));
```

R.style.ProgressDialog - your theme

Answer (score 0):

I changed **ProgressDialog**'s style from **my custom style** to  **Theme_AppCompat_Dialog**

`new ProgressDialog(mContext, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog)`

This solved the issue, but couldn't find out the reason for the problem.